# How to show date and time of modification and insertion for each row has data in the specific table/view of SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have old database and I have only read permission, inside this database has tables and views, and I need to view date and time of modification and insertion for each row has data in the specific table/view.

**Note:** I don't have column to view the date and time in the table/view.

I try to find query to show date and time of modification and insertion for each row has data in the table/view. Or any way to show date and time of modification and insertion for each row in the table/view.

Comment: If you didn't store that information on creation, it's not there. SQL Server does not record this anywhere by itself.

Comment: There's no such way. You can sometimes be able to get table modification date by groveling around in dynamic management views. Or you can parse the output of FN_DBLOG, but that is too complex to figure out exact row per row data

Comment: Depending on your need, perhaps you should be looking at a temporal table, as that stores a history of the data *and* the times when those occur. If it's only a log of change dates, with no details fo *what8 changed, then you'll likely need to enforce the use of procedures to `INSERT`/`UPDATE` the data or use `TRIGGER`s to `INSERT` the log data into another table.

Comment: btw, view doesn't contain any data per se. It's just a forwarded ehm, view of the data from the underlying tables. Just bite the bullet and create "changeDate" columns and consider the old history lost to mankind